# How to directly connect a Tripole to a wire 'without' using node

Tags: circuitikz

I stumbled on this in the circuitikz [examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/insulated-gate-bipolar-transistor/) website.

Maybe there is something I'm missing, but it seems to me that the person who wrote this, didn't bother to create a node for is tripoles.

So, is there a way for me to do something similar with an Op Amp ?

This is my code; let's say I would like to go from `(C2pos)` to `(opamp.-)`.
Is that possible ?

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american inductors]
\draw
(0,0) 
    to[short] ++(2,0) coordinate (C2pos)
    to[C, l_=$C_1$] ($(C2pos)+(0,-3)$) node[ground] {}
(5,-.5) node[op amp] (opamp){}
    (opamp.down) ++ (0,-.5) node[below] {$-Va$}
    -- (opamp.down)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

As you can see, my habit is to decrement of .5 to align `(opamp.-)` or `(opamp.+)` with the wire I want to get connected with.

But I would like to write something like this instead:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american inductors]
\draw
(0,0) 
    to[short] ++(2,0) coordinate (C2pos)
    to[C, l_=$C_1$] ($(C2pos)+(0,-3)$) node[ground] {}
(C2pos) to [op amp] (opamp){}
    (opamp.down) ++ (0,-.5) node[below] {$-Va$}
    -- (opamp.down)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

But obviously with the `(C2pos) to [op amp] (opamp){}` part being something like `(C2pos) to [op amp.-] (opamp){}` or `(C2pos) to [op amp] (opamp.-){}`. But these don't work.

So I also tried `(C2pos) to [Topamp.-,n=opamp] (opamp){}` something like that..

This is the code from the [example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/insulated-gate-bipolar-transistor/) :

```
\begin{circuitikz}

\draw (0,2) to[Tpnp,n=pnp] (0,0)
  (pnp.E) node[below=2mm] {C} % Collector (of the (whole) IGBT)
  (pnp.B) node[left=7mm] {pnp}

  (0,7) to[R,l_=$R_B$] (0,5) -- (pnp.C) % body region spreading resistance

  (0,7) -- (5,7)

  to[Tnigfete,n=mosfet] (5,5) % MOSFET
  to[Tnjfet,n=jfet,mirror] (5,3) % JFET
  to[R,l=$R_{\text{mod}}$] (5,1) % drift region resistance (modulated)
  -- (pnp.B)

  (mosfet.G) node[anchor=west] {G} % Gate
  (mosfet.B) node[anchor=east] {MOSFET}
  (jfet) node[anchor=west] {JFET}

  (2,7) -- (2,6) to[Tnpn,n=npn,mirror] (2,4) -- (2,1)
  (npn.B) -- (0,5)
  (npn.B) node[right=7mm] {npn}

  (3,7.5) to[short,n=IGBTE] (3,7) % Emitter
  (IGBTE) node[above=2mm] {E};
\end{scope}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "what you would like" block you are missing `node` (op amp is a style of `node`), an offset between `C2pos` and the op amp node (otherwise the op amp is drawn at `C2pos`), and an indication that the inverting input should be the anchor (otherwise the op amp is drawn at the center, which is the default).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american inductors]
\draw
(0,0) 
    to[short] ++(2,0) coordinate (C2pos)
    to[C, l_=$C_1$] ($(C2pos)+(0,-3)$) node[ground] {}
(C2pos) to ++(2,0) node [op amp,anchor=-] (opamp){}
    (opamp.down) ++ (0,-.5) node[below] {$-Va$}
    -- (opamp.down)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: connected op amp]